# how to type cast in mono for anddroid?

Tags: c#, android, casting, mono, type-conversion

i'm nearly to getting crazy with this problem.

i want to convert a TextView to double format but which way i go is left run time error.

the ways i tried:

```
 //first

var enterButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.enterGN);
            var inPop = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.inPopulationIn);
            var goodPop = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.goodPopIn);
            var yearsNumIn = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.yearNumIn);
            var growingRate =FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.growingRateIn);


            int InPop = Int32.Parse(inPop.ToString());
            int GoodPop = Int32.Parse(goodPop.ToString());
            int YearsNum = Int32.Parse(yearsNumIn.ToString());
            double GrowingRate = Int32.Parse(growingRate.ToString());



//second

var enterButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.enterGN);
            var inPop = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.inPopulationIn);
            var goodPop = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.goodPopIn);
            var yearsNumIn = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.yearNumIn);
            var growingRate =FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.growingRateIn);

            string inPops=inpop.ToString();
            string ...

            int InPop = System.Convert.ToInt32(inPops);
            int ....
```

Please Help Me...
Error Is Saying :

Unhandled Exception:

System.FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format

Comment: When I do any kind of parsing I keep everything the same, like  `double GrowingRate = double.Parse(growingRate.ToString());`

Comment: i Fixed It but problem didnt fix

it sayas :
Unhandled Exception:

System.FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format

Comment: What are the contents of the string you are trying to convert?

Comment: I try to create a app that calc growing population of city.
I Need To Convert All Of My Variables To int and double.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem Has Been Solved ^__^

```
EditText inPop = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.inPopulationIn);

int InPop=Int32.Parse(inPop.Text);
```

`System.Convert.ToInt32` is not working in Mono For Android But Upper Code Is Saying How To Convert Your Variable.